# How do I select from the correct database and schema?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11G. How do I provide the dbname and schema name in a query like `select * from dbname.schemaname.table`. I want to know the syntax.

If I write the query `select * from employees` and I get the error

> Table or view does not exist

I believe I have to give the name as `dbname.schemaname.tablename` but I dont know the syntax. Can someone please help?

Comment: Why do you need the DBname was it not provided in the connection string?  Schema is only needed if you're referencing a schema other than that of the logged in user.  DB links can be referenced using @ so `schema.table@link`  `Select * from ALL_DB_LINKS` will show you the links accessible for the logged in user.  maybe the DBLink was what you're after?

Comment: Are you sure the table exists at all? That table is one that may be in the default HR schema, *if it was installed*, so if you aren't logged in as HR you can `select * from hr.employees` - but only if it does exist there and you have the right permissions to see it. Why do you think you need `dbname`, is that based on a different database platform?

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to query from another schema you can do it like this:

```
select * from HR.Employees
```

where **HR** is the name of schema, any way you must grant select privilege to the schema reading from the other one, or grant dba to the schema that execute the query like this

```
grant dba to my_user;
```

where **my_user** is the user that you execute your query from.

If you want to read data from other database not that you are connecting go you can do it using database link like this:

```
    create database link "my_link"
 connect to "HR" identified by "hr"
 using '(DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS_LIST =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.200)(PORT = 1521))
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SID = ORACLE)
       )
     )'
/
```

where host is the server where the other database is installed and sid is the name of database.

and then execute your query like this:

```
select * from employees@my_Link;
```

Answer (score 0):

**create public SYNONYM to object**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM suppliers
FOR app.suppliers;
```

before SYNONYM your select is :

```
select * from app.suppliers;
```

after SYNONYM :

```
select * from suppliers;
```